# Entity Framework Changetracker not showing changes

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an issue where the `ChangeTracker.Entries` is not showing any changes that are being made.  The way I'm handling this is when I save changes on a POST.  This is mainly when modifying a current db entry.

`dbContext.SaveChanges();`

I run this method

```
 public override int SaveChanges()
 {
     ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
     var ent = new NewDBEntities();
     ent.context_SavingChanges();
     return base.SaveChanges();
 }
```

When I'm checking for the changes I run this line

```
var entities = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Added || x.State == EntityState.Deleted || x.State == EntityState.Modified).ToList();
```

However, it comes back with 0 items.  I've tried modifying, adding new, etc.

Comment: Where is you adding or modifying entities code?

Comment: We are converting over from Telerik Open Access.  When we update a record its just running "SaveChanges"

Comment: Have you turned off the automatic change detection?  Otherwise much of this code isn't needed.  If you have turned off automatic change detection, is your code flagging the change tracker when you do make the changes?

Comment: It's not clear at which moment the last line runs.

Answer (score 0):

The changes cleared once `SaveChanges()` is called.
Also, the Context lost if you registered the dbContext as a `Transient`.

It worked for me after I changed it from

```
services.AddDbContext<DBContext>(
                    options => options.UseMySql(
                        connectionString,
                        new MySqlServerVersion(new Version(8, 0, 21))
                    ), ServiceLifetime.Transient
```

to

```
services.AddDbContext<DBContext>(
                    options => options.UseMySql(
                        connectionString,
                        new MySqlServerVersion(new Version(8, 0, 21))
                    ), ServiceLifetime.Scoped
```